# How to add constraints to relationships, while using JDL studio?

Tags: jhipster, jdl

[JHipster Generator 4.14.4]

i generate an "article" with some relationships with JDL Studio. Relationships in my article.json look like this :

```
    "relationships": [
    {
        "relationshipType": "one-to-one",
        "relationshipName": "adress",
        "otherEntityName": "adressDomain",
        "otherEntityField": "id",
        "ownerSide": true,
        "otherEntityRelationshipName": "article"
    },
```

How can i add the *required* rules to my relationship?

i tried `"relationshipValidateRules": "required"` but it doesnt works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Answer is not to change in the JSON File but to regenerate the *.jh file on JDL-Studio.

Here is how to add the required:

```
relationship OneToOne {
   Article{adress required} to AdressDomain
}
```